# Solver doesnt try to optimize solution ( one hard constraint, one soft constraint )

Tags: optaplanner

I got 2 constraints :

one HARD ( 100 score )
one SOFT ( 100 score )

When i run the solver, it's like he just try to resolve the hard one, and doesn't look for the soft one. I have no softScore, optaplanner return a 0Hard/0Medium/0Soft.

**My HARD constraint is** : a worker can't work more than 5 days in a row

**My SOFT constraint is** : try to put the most of working days possible ( calculated by hours of work )

My test is for two weeks. A worker need to be above 66 hours of work, is he is under we penalize more.

Here the two constraints in JAVA:

the SOFT one :

```
  private Constraint averageWorkingHours(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .from(WorkingDay.class)
                .filter((wd) -> wd.isFreeToWork())
                .groupBy(WorkingDay::getAgent,
                        WorkingDay::hasBreakDayBySolver,
                // hasBreakDayBySolver return if the solver has put my 
                @PlanningVariable ( a breakDay ) in the WorkingDay
                        ConstraintCollectors.count())
                .filter((agent, hasBreakDayBySolver, count) -> {
                    return !hasBreakDayBySolver;
                })
                .penalizeConfigurable(AVERAGE_HOURS_WORKING, ((agent, hasBreakDayBySolver, count) -> {
                    // a worker need to be above 66 hours of work for 2 weeks
                    
                    // We penalize more if a worker is under the average of working hours wanted for two weeks ( 66 )
                    if(count * 7 < 66){  // count * hours worked for one day
                        return (66 - count * 7) * 2 ;
                    }
                    else{
                        return count * 7 - 66;
                    }
                }));
    }
```

the HARD one :

```
private Constraint fiveConsecutiveWorkingDaysMax(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory
            .from(WorkingDay.class)
            .filter(WorkingDay::hasWork)
            .join(constraintFactory.from(WorkingDay.class)
                            .filter(WorkingDay::hasWork),
                    Joiners.equal(WorkingDay::getAgent),
                    Joiners.greaterThan(wd->wd.getDayJava()),
                    Joiners.filtering((wd1, wd2)->{
                        LocalDate fourDaysBefore = wd1.getDayJava().minusDays(4);
                        Boolean wd2isAfterFourDaysBeforeWd1 = wd2.getDayJava().compareTo(fourDaysBefore) >= 0;
                        return wd2isAfterFourDaysBeforeWd1;
                    })
            )
            .groupBy((wd1, wd2) -> wd2, ConstraintCollectors.countBi())
            .filter((wd2, count) -> count >= 4) 
            .penalizeConfigurable(FIVE_CONSECUTIVE_WORKING_DAYS_MAX,((wd2, count)-> count - 3));
}
```

I hope my explanations are clear.

Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

1. [Unit test your constraints](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsTesting), using a ConstraintVerfier. [See also this short video by Lukas.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3J7jY3xZkw)
2. Verify that your `@ConstraintWeight` for that soft constraint in your dataset isn't zero.

Comment: If i put my two constraints with a soft score it work well. Only when i put my constraint "fiveConsecutiveWorkingDaysMax" in hardScore, the other one doesnt work ( like she is useless for the solver ).

Comment: @ConstraintWeight(FIVE_CONSECUTIVE_WORKING_DAYS_MAX)
    private HardMediumSoftScore fiveConsecutiveWorkingDaysMax = HardMediumSoftScore.ofHard(100);

Comment: @ConstraintWeight(AVERAGE_HOURS_WORKING)
    private HardMediumSoftScore averageWorkingHours = HardMediumSoftScore.ofSoft(100);

Comment: On a small dataset I presume... We sometimes run into this on smaller datasets. [More complex moves](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/move) typically resolve it, but they are a bit of a pain. Future versions will support such cases better.